# How to open dynamic class as static in "using" definition section?

Tags: c#, .net, using, mixins

So I want to open dynamic class as something like that :

```
using System ...
...
using System.Windows.Forms;
using core = new myNamespace.myClass(); // Sure it doesn't work but how to realize it ?
```

when I do

using myNamespace.myClass(); I can't use it because myClass is dynamic but I want it creates as this class creates and being dispose with it. And I want to have access varables / methods of myClass aslike as from this class, like

core.X must be as same as X.

probably I just want something like Interface, but as a class.

Ok I will try to explain exactly what I want to get :

for example I've got partial classes, and each one with 2 files ! and ... the content of second file is the same. How do I use one file for all partial classes ? like a module but without prefix !

so I know my English isn't perfect , I will add a code example :

```
public partial class FRIIB : Form
{
  private string x = username;
}

public partial class FRIIB : Form
{
  private string username = "hi";
}

public partial class LOLO : Form
{
  private string x = username;
  // I don't want to create another file with "username" definition 
}
```

I was thinking about using [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) ... it's looking like exactly what I want to get.

Comment: Are you confusing this with the using statement used inside the code (which guarantees Dispose() being called)? Because what you try to do isn't possible.

Comment: Do you want to create the alias of myClass?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: That is not about Dispose , I just want to have open access without calling core.X , I want to call X (and it will be from core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `using` ***statement*** needs to be within the context/scope of a *single method*.

If you can't constrain the scope to a method, you'll need to dispose it manually, usually be implementing `IDisposable` on an object, and doing the dispose in `Dispose()`. Sometimes (but very rarely) you might also want a finalizer to catch undisposed objects as the get collected - but emphasis: very rare.

There is no inbuilt mechanism for disposing *static* fields - you'd have to add a static `Release()` method (or similar) to call during clean app-exit.

There is also a `using` ***alias*** which looks a bit like your code, but does something completely unrelated (it allows you to use an alternative name for a single type, either for convenience or to avoid ambiguity; it is limited to the single file).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, then you're looking for something like this:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.LoadFrom("My Assembly").GetType("myNamespace.myClass", true));
core = obj as myNamespace.myClass;
```

The first statement creates dynamically an instance of your custom type. The second statement casts the created object to your custom type.

This code snippet shows only positive flow, while, of course, I recommend in your code minding the negative flow as well.

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Read about:

[using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)